# Authenticate restframework User in python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So, i new in django and djangorestframework. i followed their tutorial in their page. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

in that tutorial, you can login as django user from djangorestframework api login page. my question is, if i want to make a CLI or GUI application and using requests module to post a content to the API, but the API must be loggged in first. how i do that?

Comment: You can use token auth: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: @neverwalkaloner , it is tell from server side right? how about the client side? how to pass the token if i use requests module?

Comment: Something like this `response = requests.get('<MY_URI>', headers={'Authorization': 'Token <MY_TOKEN>'})`. Authorization header will authenticate user.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner thanks. i somehow get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DRF, you can add additional package for simple token-based Authentication. Add `rest_framework.authtoken` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. To make HTTP(S) request to client you pass the authorization token like this `Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b`

For testing, you can use curl

`curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b`

[Read more...](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. though someone already made a comment and i already try it. I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set that a user must be authenticated at all times as default setting in settings.py (in your web server project):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
```

More info about that [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/).

In your web client project, like one of the comments on your questions mentions, you must add an Authentication header in the HTTP messages you send to the web server. An example (TypeScript Angular application implementation) would be:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Spacecraft} from '../model/spacecraft';

/* Create the authentication headers for the HTTP requests to the DRF project's API.
 * Note: uses btoa(): base-64 encoding of ASCII string, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa.
 */
const basicAuthenticationToken = btoa(environment.REST_API.username + ':' + environment.REST_API.password);
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': `Basic ${basicAuthenticationToken}`
  })
};

@Injectable()
export class APICommunicationService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private notificationsService: NotificationsService) {
  }

  getSpacecraftInfo(url: string): Observable<Spacecraft> {
    return this.http.get<Spacecraft>(url, httpOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decide to go with other answer, and that's through token authentication. And i'm talking about implementation in GUI app like PyQt, I didn't learn angular js at all tho. but i appreciate your help.